# Armazenando valor de um campo input, em um localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Estou tentando pegar o conteúdo de um campo input no html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="tarefa" placeholder="Insira sua tarefa">

    <button onclick="Value1()">Pegar dado</button>

    <button onclick="limpar()">Limpar localStorage</button>


    <button onclick="exibir()">Exibir</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Veja meu Javascript**

```
//Função para pegar o dado
function Value1()
{
alert(localStorage.setItem('arquivo1', document.body.tarefa.value));
}


//Função para exibir o que foi pego
function exibir(){
    alert("O valor guardado e: " + localStorage.getItem("arquivo1"))
}


//Função para apagar o que esta definido no localStorage
function limpar(){
    localStorage.removeItem("arquivo1");
```

Porém quando clico para exibir o alert, esta dando indefinido, não consegui encontrar solução para este problema.

Meu novo código:
Mesmo assim, continua aparecendo com nulo o valor.

```
//Função para pegar o dado
function Value1()
{

var tarefa = document.querySelector("#tarefa").value;
localStorage.getItem("arquivo1", tarefa);
console.log(tarefa);
}


//Função para exibir o que foi pego
function exibir(){
    alert("O valor guardado e: " + localStorage.getItem("arquivo1"))
}


//Função para apagar o que esta definido no localStorage
function limpar(){
    localStorage.removeItem("arquivo1");
}
```

Comment: pode compartilhar o html inteiro? onde está o elemento `tarefa`? O programa está tentando acessar o valor desse elemento, mas não está conseguindo, pois ele não está definido no html que você compartilhou.

Comment: Pronto, adicionei todo código html

Comment: Seu problema é aqui `document.body.tarefa.value`, não existe essa sintaxe no **JavaScript**, vc pode pegar o valor do **`input`** de diversas formas, por id, tag, class, querySelector, querySelectorAll.

Comment: Comentei outro código, mesmo assim continua aparecendo como nulo.

Comment: Sim vai continuar como `nulo` pq está pegando o valor do input pelo **id document.querySelector("#tarefa").value** só que no seu **`HTML`** não tem nenhum input com o id **tarefa**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O valor aparece como nulo pois a sua `input` não possui `id`, além disso na função `Value1` você está utilizando `localStorage.getItem`, utilizada para buscar um valor salvo no `localStorage`.

Código refatorado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="tarefa"
      placeholder="Insira sua tarefa"
      id="tarefa"
    />

    <button onclick="saveDataToLocalStorage()">Pegar dado</button>
    <button onclick="clearLocalStorage()">Limpar localStorage</button>
    <button onclick="showLocalStorageData()">Exibir</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
/**
 * Função para salvar os dados digitados na input
 * para o localStorage
 */
function saveDataToLocalStorage() {
  const tarefa = document.querySelector("#tarefa").value;
  localStorage.setItem("arquivo1", tarefa);
  console.log(tarefa);
}

/**
 * Função para exibir o dado salvo no localStorage
 */
function showLocalStorageData() {
  alert("O valor guardado é: " + localStorage.getItem("arquivo1"));
}

/**
 * Função para limpar os dados salvos no localStorage
 */
function clearLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.removeItem("arquivo1");
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!